# Incorporate nm-applet in i3 window manager

Tags: linux, networkmanager, i3, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu 17.04 with i3 window manager. I am tryig to open the network manager from the i3wm but I can't. The internet connection works by going to the defaiult network that I set via LXDE, however unless I log back in via LXDE, I can't change the network via nm-applet. When I run `nm-applet` in the terminal in i3, nothing happens. Any suggestions? (I just want to be able to change between the wifi networks using the mouse, I don't want to work in the command line for that.)

Addendum:

Here is the output of `systemctl status dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service`

```
● NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-06-25 21:35:57 EDT; 967ms ago
 Main PID: 1477 (nm-dispatcher)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
           └─1477 /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dispatcher

Jun 25 21:35:57 dot-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-USDT-PC systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 25 21:35:57 dot-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-USDT-PC systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 25 21:35:57 dot-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-USDT-PC nm-dispatcher[1477]: req:1 'dhcp6-change' [wlxc83a35c67f33]: new request (1 scripts)
Jun 25 21:35:57 dot-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-USDT-PC nm-dispatcher[1477]: req:1 'dhcp6-change' [wlxc83a35c67f33]: start running ordered scripts.
lines 1-12/12 (END)
```

Update 2:

I was able to pinpoint to the problem and it is a strange one (does not change with `exec_always`): When I use an additional screen, then the `nm-applet` does not show up while everything else is there. If I disconnect the second monitor and reboot the PC, it shows up in the rigth lower corner as it's supposed to.

Comment: Have you tried adding `exec --no-startup-id nm-applet` to your i3 config? What does `systemctl status dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service` return during an i3 session?

Comment: @RichardBorder actually after I rebooted it it is no longer working. The output to your command is incorporated in the updated post above.

Comment: howabout adding `exec_always --no-startup-id nm-applet` instead? also, try `systemctl enable network-manager.service`

Comment: @RichardBorder I was able to pinpoint to the problem and it is a strange one (does not change with `exec_always`): When I use an additional screen, then the `nm-applet` does not show up while everything else is there. If I disconnect the second monitor and reboot the PC, it shows up in the rigth lower corner as it's supposed to.

Comment: Do any other tray icons show up with both monitors? You might just need to set a primary monitor via xrandr or arandr or set your `tray_output` to the specific display you want in your i3 conf

Comment: @RichardBorder well, the other montior is a TV that has some overscan problem (that's a separate issue) so I don't see the very top and bottom of its screen. But I can tell you that no other icon is missing from the main PC screen which is already set as a primary monitor.

Comment: Hope it works in your i3 config `# show tray icons on the primary monitor
bar {
    tray_output primary
}`   source https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_tray_outputhttps://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_tray_output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying numerous suggestions found here and elsewhere, my solution was:

```
bar {
         tray_output primary
         status_command i3status
}
```

be careful with the c&p, not sure it'll format correctly

Comment: you added this at the end of the config file?

Comment: I've found that I have to toggle `output` or `tray_output` on and off (commenting and restarting i3) depending on the machine I'm on and the video card drivers and monitor layout present. Plugging in an external monitor tends to break the tray because "primary" might change, I need to dig in sometime but with a 4K laptop I haven't had much incentive yet.

Answer (score 6):

Per the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Checking_connectivity) try:

```
exec --no-startup-id nm-applet --sm-disable
```

in your .i3config.  That's supposed to fix issues with non-XDG WMs.  I'm running i3 (single monitor though, so results might be skewed) and run it that way.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: Worked perfectly on lubuntu